# displaying menu and menu items

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have `NSTableView` object. I need to invoke the menu associated with it at my control at any point of time. And through that I should invoke `menuNeedsUpdate` method for menu updates.

```
class MyClass
{
  IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
  IBOutlet NSMenu *mMenu;
}

//methods 

void menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu*)inMenu
{
   // do menu settings here

}

 void myMethod:(id)inTableView
{

  NSInteger row = [inTableView selectedRow];

  //some condition checking here

  // invoke menu of the tableView

}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Seems you have not read the my queries properly...

Comment: There's no question here. Not even a question mark. What are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to subclass NSTableView and implement `- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent`

A tipical way to get row is

```
- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSPoint where = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    NSInteger row = [self rowAtPoint:where];
}
```

Comment: Yes this will return the menu for corresponding tableview. How can I tell to show the menu.

Comment: You can implement + (NSMenu *)defaultMenu then inside menuForEvent modify it (disabling items or adding other) calling [[self class] defaultMenu];